# MYSQL CONCAT Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a table like this below. and table name is sample.

```
id | product
--------------
1   | pen
1   | book
1   | eraser
2   | mouse
2   | keyboard
```

I need an output like this by using procedure. thanks advance

```
id | product
-------------
1  | pen,book,eraser
2  | mouse,keyboard
```

Comment: you can use group_concat

Comment: thanks..i got that. but i need as procedure not as simple query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go try this procedure :

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName()

BEGIN

SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(product)  FROM sample group by id;

END //

DELIMITER ;

It is not well tested I believe you can debug it. 
For reference you can go through the following tutorial it will give you basic idea : 
[Mysql Store Procedure Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx)

Comment: thanks that's great and simple..here my colleague confused me by using loop conditions by checking every line vice versa. is there a way kind of using looping conditions?

Comment: No need to give any loop here. Mysql scan the full table with given condition and give you the result.

Answer (score 1):

Writing procedures are as simple as writing SQL queries. For your requirement, a tested procedure is:

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `getConcatedProduct` ()
    BEGIN
       -- this is a comment
       SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(product) FROM sample group by id;
    END
```

Comment: so can you accept my answer? so that others searching for same topic will know that this is a working solution!!